# GitHub PR analysis from SonarCloud

Tags: sonarcloud

Does sonarcloud runs analysis on GitHub PR once the PR is created? or we have to trigger PR analysis through sonar-scanner? If it triggers automatically, is linking (adding github token) to sonarcloud sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, SonarCloud does not trigger the analysis on its own. You have to configure your CI engine/service to execute the SonarScanner with the relevant parameters to have your PR analysed and decorated.

You can read more on how to do this on [this following blog post](https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud-loves-your-build-pipeline).

Comment: Hello @Fabrice, I'm bit confused with the documentation here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/

Will the `sonar-scanner` script push the code specifically from the branch the PR is created from? Also will it give me analysis on only the new code I have added in the PR or will it perform analysis of all the code in the repository?

Also, in order to see a PR check on GitHub for SonarCloud, I need to set up both sonar-scanner in my .travis.yml file AND configure the SonarCloud app on GitHub. Is that right?

Comment: What I want to do is get sonarcloud analysis on *only* the new code I check-in the PR. Not all the code in the branch